# comparing two lists of unequal length at each index

Tags: list, python-2.7, python-itertools

I have two lists of unequal length such as

```
            list1 = ['G','T','C','A','G']
            list2 = ['AAAAA','TTTT','GGGG','CCCCCCCC']
```

- I want to compare these two lists at each index only against the corresponding positions i.e list2[0] against list1[0] and list2[1] against list1[1] and so on upto the length of list1.
- And get two new lists one having the mismatches and the second having the position of mismatches for example in the language of coding it can be stated as :

  ```
        if 'G' == 'GGG' or 'G' # where 'G' is from list1[1] and 'GGG' is from list2[2] 
        elif 'G' == 'AAA'     
        {
        outlist1 == list1[index] # postion of mismatch 
        outlist2 == 'G/A'
        }
  ```

Comment: I don't understand how you want to compare the elements of each list. Can you give full expected output for `outlist1` and `outlist2` from your example above?

Comment: This `if 'G' == 'GGG' or 'G'` statement is totaly wrong written. It will __always__ evaluate to __True__.

Comment: rbierman its simple.  That where on an index the characters of both the lists are same (in content) i.e there is G in list1 and GGG in list then ignore this position.And where these two positions don't match then put the character in list2 and the unmatched character in list1 like if there is G in list1 and GGA in list then we get a G/A in outlist2 and position of this index in outlist1.

Comment: complete expected output is as follows:  outlist2=[G/A,C/G,A/C] and outlist1=[0,2,3]

Comment: Nf4r please read the complete quesstion , I have only described the scenario in words of programing to make it easy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok this works. There are definitely ways to do it in less code, but I think this is pretty clear:

```
#Function to process the lists
def get_mismatches(list1,list2):
    #Prepare the output lists
    mismatch_list = []
    mismatch_pos = []

    #Figure out which list is smaller
    smaller_list_len = min(len(list1),len(list2))

    #Loop through the lists checking element by element
    for ind in range(smaller_list_len):
        elem1 = list1[ind][0] #First char of string 1, such as 'G'
        elem2 = list2[ind][0] #First char of string 2, such as 'A'

        #If they match just continue
        if elem1 == elem2:
            continue
        #If they don't match update the output lists
        else:
            mismatch_pos.append(ind)
            mismatch_list.append(elem1+'/'+elem2)

    #Return the output lists
    return mismatch_list,mismatch_pos


#Make input lists
list1 = ['G','T','C','A','G']
list2 = ['AAAAA','TTTT','GGGG','CCCCCCCC']

#Call the function to get the output lists
outlist1,outlist2 = get_mismatches(list1,list2)

#Print the output lists:
print outlist1
print outlist2
```

Output:

```
['G/A', 'C/G', 'A/C']
[0, 2, 3]
```

And just to see how short I could get the code I made this function which I think is equivalent:

```
def short_get_mismatches(l1,l2):
    o1,o2 = zip(*[(i,x[0]+'/'+y[0]) for i,(x,y) in enumerate(zip(l1,l2)) if x[0] != y[0]])
    return list(o1),list(o2)

#Make input lists
list1 = ['G','T','C','A','G']
list2 = ['AAAAA','TTTT','GGGG','CCCCCCCC']

#Call the function to get the output lists
outlist1,outlist2 = short_get_mismatches(list1,list2)
```

EDIT:

I'm not sure if I'm cleaning the sequence as you want w/ the N's and -'s. Is this the answer to the example in your comment?

```
Unclean list1 ['A', 'T', 'G', 'C', 'A', 'C', 'G', 'T', 'C', 'G']
Clean list1 ['A', 'T', 'G', 'C', 'A', 'C', 'G', 'T', 'C', 'G']

Unclean list2 ['GGG', 'TTTN', '-', 'NNN', 'AAA', 'CCC', 'GCCC', 'TTT', 'CCCTN']
Clean list2 ['GGG', 'TTT', 'AAA', 'CCC', 'GCCC', 'TTT', 'CCCT']

0 A GGG
1 T TTT
2 G AAA
3 C CCC
4 A GCCC
5 C TTT
6 G CCCT
['A/G', 'G/A', 'A/G', 'C/T', 'G/C']
[0, 2, 4, 5, 6]
```

Comment: I am sorry I missed something ,  I am modifying list1 and list2 they know becomes list1=[]

Comment: list1=['A', 'T', 'G', 'C', 'A' ,'C', 'G' , 'T' , 'C', 'G'] , list2=[ 'GGG' , 'TTTN' , ' - ' , 'NNN' , 'AAA' , 'CCC' , 'GCCC' , 'TTT' , 'CCCTN' ] and we get the output as      outlist2 =  [' A/G ' , 'G/C ' , 'C/T'] and outlist1 = [0 , 6 , 8] .

Comment: I means that the basic logic stays the same but if a ' - ' occurs then ignore it also if 'NNN' or  'N' occurs then ignore it but if it occurs like 'TTTN' then again ignores only N and compare the remaining 'TTT' with the elements in list1.

Comment: Why does the 6th index of list1, `G`, and 6th index of list2, `GCCC`, not match? Why would it produce a `G/C` output?

Answer (score 1):

this works fine for my question:

```
    #!/usr/bin/env python
    list1=['A', 'T', 'G', 'C', 'A' ,'C', 'G' , 'T' , 'C', 'G']
    list2=[ 'GGG' , 'TTTN' , ' - ' , 'NNN' , 'AAA' , 'CCC' , 'GCCC' , 'TTT'  ,'CCCATN' ]

    notifications = []
    indexes = []

    for i in range(min(len(list1), len(list2))):
        item1 = list1[i]
        item2 = list2[i]

    # Skip ' - '
    if item2 == ' - ':
        continue

    # Remove N since it's a wildcard
    item2 = item2.replace('N', '')

    # Remove item1
    item2 = item2.replace(item1, '')

    chars = set(item2)

    # All matched
    if len(chars) == 0:
       continue

    notifications.append('{}/{}'.format(item1, '/'.join(set(item2))))
    indexes.append(i)

    print(notifications)
    print(indexes)
```

It gives the output as

- ['A/G', 'G/C', 'C/A/T']
- [0, 6, 8]